How do people calculate eigenstate amplitudes for finite lattices
I'm given the hamiltonian of a generalized Hatano-Nelson chain,
$$ H_{lr} = \sum_{n=1}^{N} (t_l c_n^\dagger c_{n+l} + t_{-r} c_n^\dagger c_{n-r})$$
How would one normally go about finding the spatial distribution of the eigenstates for the finite lattice with $N$ sites numerically? What exactly do $c_i^\dagger$ and $c_i$ represent in the matrix form? Is the one below correct? What should be the size of the matrices that one use for numerical computation?
I am an absolute beginner to many-body quantum systems. It would be great if anyone can recommend any useful resources to read up about this. Thank you!
$$c^\dagger_i = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots \\
\sqrt{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots \\
0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & \dots & 0 & \dots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \dots & \dots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & \sqrt{i} & 0 & \dots & \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots \end{pmatrix} $$

I thought Hatano-Nelson is a fermionic chain.  If so, your formula for $c^\dagger$ is not correct. It should be 2-by-2 matrix.

How would the operator on the nth site look like?
